# Android: column _id does not exist

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm currently working on loading the data from SQLite database to ListView. So I'm using the `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Here's the `initListView()` method in the activity part that loads data and shows in the list view.

```
private void initListView() {

    Cursor cursor = db.fetchAllPostLists();
    String[] columns = {
            DataKeyLists.KEY_UPLOADER,
            DataKeyLists.KEY_CONTENT,
            DataKeyLists.KEY_UPLOADED_AT
    };

    int[] to = {
            R.id.tvFeedUsername,
            R.id.tvFeedText,
            R.id.tvFeedCreated,
    };

    FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(this, R.layout.feed_item, cursor, columns, to, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

the `FeedAdapter` class is as follows.

```
public class FeedAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public FeedAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to, flags);
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
}
```

When I try to open the activity, the app quits, leaving this message: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist`

According to the LogCat, the exception is caused in the `super()` constructor part in the `FeedAdapter` class. How should I solve this?

**Edited**
This is the `fetchAllPostLists()` method.

```
public Cursor fetchAllPostLists() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_POST, new String[] {KEY_POST_ID, KEY_UPLOADER, KEY_CONTENT, KEY_PRIVACY_LEVEL, KEY_UPLOADED_AT, KEY_EDITED_AT}, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    db.close();

    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: show `fetchAllPostLists ` method code

Comment: `KEY_POST_ID` value should be `_id`